# Missing Attribute in a Python HTML request

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm a newbie to Python and I'm actually working on a little Python script that **request and read the HTML of an URL**.

For Information the web page that i'm working on is http://bitcoinity.org/markets , 
I would like with my script to fetch the Current Price of the market.
I checked the HTML code and i found that the Price was in a  balise :

```
<span id="last_price" value="447.77"</span>
```

Here is the code of my Python script :

```
import urllib2
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://bitcoinity.org/markets"
values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
      'location' : 'Northampton',
      'language' : 'Python' }
user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
HTML = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML)
HTMLText = HTML.read()
HTML.close()
#print soup.prettify()
#print HTMLText
```

So the problem is that the output of this script ( with the 2 methods BeautifulSoup and read() ) is like this :

```
</span>
<span id="last_price">
</span>
```

**The "value=" attribute is missing and the syntax changed** , so I don't know if the server doesn't allow me to make a request of this value or if there is a problem with my code.

All Help is welcome ! :)

( Sorry for my bad english , i'm not a native )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The price is calculated via a set of javascript functions, `urllib2`+`BeautifulSoup` approach would not work in this case.

Consider using a tool that utilizes a real browser, like [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/):

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> driver.get('http://bitcoinity.org/markets')
>>> driver.find_element_by_id('last_price').text
u'0.448'
```

Comment: @alecxe Thanks it was exactly what i was searching for !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure beautifulsoup or selenium are the tools for this task. They're actually a very poor solution.

Since we're talking about "stock" prices (bitcoin in this case), it is much better if you feed your app/script with real-time market data. Bitcoinity's default "current price" is actually Bitstamp's price... You can also get it directly from the **[Bitstamp's API](https://www.bitstamp.net/api/)** via 2 ways.

## HTTP API

Here's the ticker you need to feed your app with: https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/ and here how you can get the last price (It is the 'last' value of that JSON what you really are looking for)

```
import urllib2
import json

req = urllib2.Request("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/")
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
f = opener.open(req)
json = json.loads(f.read())
print 'Bitcoin last price is = '+json['last']
```

## Websockets API

This is how bitcoinity, bitcoinwisdom, etc grab the prices and market info in order to show it to you in real-time. For this you'll need pusher package for python, since [Bitstamp uses pusher](https://www.bitstamp.net/websocket/) for websockets.

Comment: That's a good point. I was thinking about API solution, but haven't noticed that `bitcoinity` uses `Bitstamp`'s API. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! but i was interested in the global case of parsing html pages , the bitcoin price was just an example but thanks for the API trick :)